# Visualizing the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is defined as the maximum distance between the empirical and the hypothesized cumulative distribution function. Rather than looking at numbers, I think it is much preferable to locate the maximum difference using a graph.

I know how to plot the empirical distribution function

> p1<-qplot(rnorm(30),stat="ecdf",geom="step")

but could you please tell me how I could add on the same plot the cumulative distribution function of the theoretical distribution? For my case, the theoretical distribution is the standard normal but I am interested in the generalization to every distribution function.

Thank you.

Comment: Just use `pnorm`: `x <- seq(-3, 3, length = 100); plot(x, pnorm(x))`. For other distributions, use e.g. `pbeta`, `pcauchy`, etc.

Comment: @Gregor I see, but how can you add that on an existing ggplot2 plot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use `ggplot`, just do

```
set.seed(15)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30))
ggplot(dd, aes(x)) +
    stat_ecdf() + 
    stat_function(fun = pnorm, colour = "red")
```

You can find the maximal distance if you like with

```
ed <- ecdf(dd$x)
maxdiffidx <- which.max(abs(ed(dd$x)-pnorm(dd$x)))
maxdiffat <- dd$x[maxdiffidx]
```

and add that to the plot with

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x)) +
    stat_ecdf() + 
    stat_function(fun = pnorm, colour = "red") + 
    geom_vline(x=maxdiffat, lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you. Is there a way to limit the vertical line between the two functions?

Comment: Not with `vline`, you could draw a `segment` instead to give explicit start/end points.

Comment: Alright. But how about another distribution function, say the distribution function of gamma with parameters 2 and 3?

Comment: You just use `stat_function` with whatever function you want. Instead of `pnorm`, use `pgamma`. See the documentation for [stat_function](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_function.html)